# What is the best SE site to ask about comparing web streaming 1080p to blu ray quality?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask for a comparison in quality of streaming 1080p movies via Netflix or now Apple iTunes compared to the traditional blu ray disc.

What's the best Stack Exchange site to do so?

Comment: This is a comment to your question because it's not an answer to your meta question, but streaming 1080p almost always compresses the signal more than blu-ray to reduce the required bandwith, so the picture quality is always going to be varying degrees of less quality than a blu ray.  That said, you can get very good HD quality if you have a very high-speed Internet connection, and a dedicated player like a Roku.

Comment: See also http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064  Consider supporting this proposal.  I think, with the right approach, SE could benefit tremendously from a Consumer Electronics site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this isn't a subjective question, I think that [movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com) would be suitable enough for this purpose.

Ask yourself: Can this be answered 20 ways or just 2? If you answer yourself "20 ways", there's no Stack Exchange site suitable for your question.